# How to attach elisp function source code in Emacs?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, emacs, elisp

I could use `M-x find-function` to find the source code of some elisp functions if the function is not written in C code.

But since I am using a **Debian binary package** of Emacs , some of the source code is omitted and only the byte-compiled `.elc` files preserved. So is there any way to get the source code and attach them with those elc files? Can I use `apt-get source emacs` and associate with the src (**C code** as well) with the byte-compiled one. Or do I have to build Emacs from source code?

Comment: An educated guess is that you need to install `emacs23-el` or `emacs24-el`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the installation smaller, Debian's [`emacs`](http://packages.debian.org/emacs) metapackage does not include the Elisp source code (as you've noticed).  Debian packages that in `emacsVERSION-el`.  There is no `emacs-el` metapackage, so you'll have to install the `-el` package for the appropriate version of Emacs.

Currently, that's [`emacs23-el`](http://packages.debian.org/emacs23-el), because the `emacs` metapackage installs [`emacs23`](http://packages.debian.org/emacs23).